# How can I use comma seperated value stored in variable in MYSQL IN condition?

Tags: mysql, database

I have to remove certain rows from database using query. For ex I have one variable which has ids stored in comma separated pattern:

```
@ids = (1,2,3);
```

Now I want to use this ids in IN clause :

```
delete from table_name where id in (@ids);
```

But it's not working. Any suggestion or help will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Is that a Perl variable?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but isn't the variable supposed to be @ids:=(1,2,3) ?

Comment: @VikingBlooded If it's a MySQL variable, you use `:=` when it's being assigned in a query. If it's being assigned in a separate statement, you use `SET @ids = '1,2,3'`. Either way, there shouldn't be parentheses around it, it should be a quoted string. That's why I thought it was Perl.

Comment: Ah yeah. I dont do much with mySql, I just knew it didn't look right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting a variable into a query does not substitute it as a string, it's still considered a single value. So `WHERE id IN (@ids)` is not looking for any of the numbers, it's looking for an id that matches the whole string `1,2,3`.

You have to use `FIND_IN_SET` to match against a comma-separated list in a string.

```
SET @ids = '1,2,3';
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, @ids);
```